# What is the correct use of Sass/SCSS mixin arguments in this case?

Tags: sass, mixins

I have problems to use the `$image-width` and `$image-height` arguments for the `background-size` property. The CSS only works if I choose to write the arguments in place (as seen in the commented line in the code example below). The dynamic version doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Besides that, this code snippet should load an retina version only when needed by the device.
Read more on that here: [Media Query Asset Downloading](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/)

```css
/* see: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/ */
@mixin retina-background($filename, $image-width, $image-height, $extension: ".png") {
    background-image: image-url($filename + $extension);
    height: $image-height;
    width: $image-width;
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
        background-image: image-url($filename + "2x" + $extension);
        //background-size: 213px 21px;
        background-size: $image-width $image-height;
        height: $image-height;
        width: $image-width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just checked your code and it's working fine, `background-size` values are in place.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code is working fine. I've forgot to assign "px" in the arguments of my calling function. So the resulting CSS was wrong (without unit). What a useless mistake. Thanks a lot!